# Ethernet Port Shuts off When I Turn the Computer On

Tags: networking, laptop, windows-8.1, ethernet

I am having a strange problem with my ethernet cables on my laptop. I have an ethernet cable that shows all indications of functioning whenever the laptop is off, but as soon as I turn it on, the port goes dark and I cannot figure out why. In once instance, I started up my laptop, and the cable was working fine, and as soon as the internet connection icon appeared in the task tray, the port dropped off. What is causing this and what can I do about it? I am running Windows 8.1 on an HP ProBook 4540s.

**Edit: It seems to me that after leaving the cable in for an extended period of time, it detects it and starts working.**

Comment: Have you tried a different cable?

Comment: @DavidPostill My next best guess too: Flaky cable or possible flaky switchport on the other end.

Comment: How long has this problem been going on? Does it happen with all networks? What happens if you boot without the cable plugged in, then once Windows is done starting, connect the cable?

Comment: Replacing the cable for a third time seems to have done the trick, but in case it is helpful to anyone, I did try that and it did not work.

Comment: *Replacing the cable for a third time seems to have done the trick...I did try that and it did not work.* Which is it? Did replacing the cable work or not?

Comment: @Twisty Replacing the cable worked. What did not work is trying to plug in the bad cable when Windows was already running. I apologize for the ambiguity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seemed to be not with the cable that I was using to connect, but rather with the port on my router that I was connecting the cable to. Using a different port on my router seems to work just fine regardless of what cable I use.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the laptop isn't turning the wired ethernet off as soon as it establishes a WIFI connection ?
Some HP laptops do this by default. When you shut the WIFI off the wired connection comes back.

In most HP models with this feature you can disable it in the BIOS setup. (I don't know what it is called. I've never actually seen one of those models myself, but I have heard people complaining about it before.)

Comment: Yes, Wi-Fi is turned off.